# Two seperate API call values in one array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

### Situation

I have two API calls, one to get all the devices and one to get all the groups. What I would like to accomplish is to have one call that would fetch the groups with its devices.

This is the function to get the devices

```
public function getAll($environment, $options)
{
    // Get group ids from database, used for pairing groups with environments
    $groups = Device::where('source_id', $options['deviceSourceId'])->get();
    $groupIds = [];
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $groupIds[] = $group['group_id'];
    }

    // Parameters
    $apiparams = [
        'headers' => $this->getHeaders($environment)
    ];

    $devices = [];

    foreach($groupIds as $groupId)
    {
        $responseAPI = $this->getClient()->request('GET', 'devices?groupid=' . $groupId, $apiparams);
        $responseAPI = json_decode($responseAPI->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        $devices[] = $responseAPI['devices'];
    }

    return $devices;
}
```

This is the function to get the groups

```
public function getGroups($environment, $options)
{
    // Get group ids from database, used for pairing groups with environments
    $groups = Device::where('source_id', $options['deviceSourceId'])->get();
    $groupIds = [];
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $groupIds[] = $group['group_id'];
    }

    // Parameters
    $apiparams = [
        'headers' => $this->getHeaders($environment)
    ];

    $groups2 = [];

    foreach($groupIds as $groupId)
    {
        $responseAPI = $this->getClient()->request('GET', 'groups/' . $groupId, $apiparams);
        $responseAPI = json_decode($responseAPI->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        $groups2[] = $responseAPI;
    }
    return $groups2;
}
```

### Current response

This is the response I get from these.

```
// Device response
[
    {
        "remotecontrol_id": "r5674567"
        "device_id": "d871212",
        "alias": "PC-01",
        "groupid": "g9873491",
        "online_state": "Online",
        "assigned_to": false
    },
    {
        "remotecontrol_id": "r8370129"
        "device_id": "d091231",
        "alias": "PC-02",
        "groupid": "g9873491",
        "online_state": "Offline",
        "assigned_to": false
    }
]

// Group response
{
    "id": "g9873491"
    "name": "companyname",
    "permissions": "owned"
}
```

### Needed response

The response I would like to get is:

```
[{id: "g9873491",
  name: "companyname",
  devices: [{device_id: "d871212",
             alias: "PC-01",
             online_state: "Online"},
            {device_id: "d091231",
             alias: "PC-02",
             online_state: "Offline"}
            }],
}]
```

**How would I need to do this?**

### Sevavietl edit

```
public function getAll($environment, $options)
{
    // Get group ids from database, used for pairing groups with environments
    $groups = Device::where('source_id', $options['deviceSourceId'])->get();
    $groupIds = [];
    foreach ($groups as $group) {
        $groupIds[] = $group['group_id'];
    }

    // Parameters
    $apiparams = [
        'headers' => $this->getHeaders($environment)
    ];

    foreach($groupIds as $groupId)
    {

        $responseAPI1 = $this->getClient()->request('GET', 'groups/' . $groupId, $apiparams);
        $responseAPI2 = $this->getClient()->request('GET', 'devices?groupid=' . $groupId, $apiparams);

        $groups2 = json_decode($responseAPI1->getBody()->getContents(), true);
        $devices = json_decode($responseAPI2->getBody()->getContents(), true);

        $result = array_values(array_reduce(
            $devices,
            function ($carry, $device) {
                if (isset($carry[$device['groupid']])) { // Undefined index: groupid
                    // Add device to group.
                    $carry[$device['groupid']]['devices'][] = [
                        'device_id' => $device['device_id'],
                        'alias' => $device['alias'],
                        'online_state' => $device['online_state']
                    ];
                }

                return $carry;
            },
            // Reindex groups by id.
            array_column($groups2, null, 'id')
        ));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Could we get a response in text format please and not a picture? it's just slightly easier to read. If I could be a pain aswell, if the data is sensitive could you throw in some fake data so we can see what actually matches up? An example of the needed response you want with the fake data used in both API calls would go a long way aswell.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Sure, I'll edit the post!

Comment: How do you define *"online_state"*? How is your desired output related to the groups? Please clarify the structure and the information given in your desired output.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript and PhilippMaurer. I've edited the outcome I want to receive, if this isn't enough I'll provide the values of the responses I have now.

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays There's no need to compromise anything sensitive, if you could add some fake data to both your API call responses (that matches up with your needed response data) and remove those images that would help us understand slightly more what the structure looks like

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Sure, I'll do that! Brb.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Post is edited, hope it's clear now.

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays sorry I'm in a few more meetings not had chance to look at it yet.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Not a problem, take a look when u have time :)

Comment: Why won't you just do the api calls and merge the array the way you want?

Comment: @WouterVanDamme I've tried but whatever I did, I didn't get the response I needed so I asked here haha. Could you help me out with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have control over the API, I guess you cannot reduce the number of calls, as you have only calls defined by the API itself. So one solution would be to prepare the response in needed format yourself. You can do the following:

```
$devices = json_decode($devices, true);
$groups = json_decode($groups, true);

$result = array_values(array_reduce(
    $devices,
    function ($carry, $device) {
        if (isset($carry[$device['groupid']])) {
            // Add device to group.
            $carry[$device['groupid']]['devices'][] = [
                'device_id' => $device['device_id'],
                'alias' => $device['alias'],
                'online_state' => $device['online_state']
            ];
        }

        return $carry;
    },
    // Reindex groups by id.
    array_column($groups, null, 'id')
));
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/93085f1a121a7af44e147887f177aa4e598fa5f1).

As you are using Laravel, another approach would be to take advantage of [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections). But in this particular situation, I guess, unless you are the collections guru (and read ["Refactoring to Collections"](https://adamwathan.me/refactoring-to-collections/) from cover to cover:)) the plain PHP array functions is easier to understand and work with.

Comment: I'm getting an undefined index error at the If(added a comment at that line). Could you take a look at it?

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays, the id of the group must be residing under another index. Might be `'group_id'` or something like this.

Comment: Still the same, tried all possibilities. This is the response I get with the error: 'Undefined index: group_id', '/var/www/extensions/Teamviewer/API/Services/TeamviewerLocal.php', '111', array('carry' => array('g121012823', 'companyname', 'owned'), 'device' => array(array('remotecontrol_id' => 'r691200188', 'device_id' => 'd647244096', 'alias' => 'PC-01', 'groupid' => 'g547621523', 'online_state' => 'Online', 'assigned_to' => false). It does has a groupid right?

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays, well for me it is even harder to guess all the possibilities, as I cannot see the actual output of API. I think you shouldn't try all the possibilities, but simply do `var_dump($device)` before if block to see how it looks like. This might give you a hint what is wrong.

Comment: This is the output of the API. [Link](https://imgur.com/a/5LGFe). I did do the `var_dump($device)` but it looked all good to me.

Comment: @idontunderstandarrays, sorry, but it is hard to help you in such format. I think my answer should give you the basic idea of how it can be done. Try to debug and find out why there is no such offset in the array. Maybe some devices do not belong to any group. As you can see from the demo, the code works on the data format you have provided in the question. So you should figure out why the actual data doesn't follow that format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166961/discussion-between-idontunderstandarrays-and-sevavietl).